# How to create a unique toJSON method for a property defined by Object.define()

Tags: javascript, json

Lets say we have an object with a defined property that is expected to point to another object, as follows:

```
Object.defineProperty(parent, 'child', {
    enumerable: true,
    get: function() { return this._actualChild; },
    set: function(v){
      if(v && typeof v === 'object'){
            this._actualChild = v;
      } else {
        throw new TypeError('child property must be an object!')
      }
    }
  });
```

Is there a way to configure the property itself so that when it's run through `JSON.stringify()`, the toJSON of the `.child` property can be defined *uniquely* for that property?

For instance, after we have set the following:

```
var jill = {id: 3, name: 'Jill'};
parent.child = jill;
```

If we could somehow define the `toJSON` for parent.child to return the `id` property of the child. So `JSON.stringify(parent)` would return:

```
{_actualChild: {id: 3, name: 'Jill'}, child: 3}
```

We can define a toJSON for the child object itself of course, but then we would get:

```
{_actualChild: 3, child: 3}
```

I would like to separate the property toJSON method from the actual child object's toJSON method. Is this possible?

It would be really nice if I could just do something like this:

```
  Object.defineProperty(o, 'child', {
    enumerable: true,
    get: function() {
      return this._hiddenChild;
    },
    set: function(v){
      if(v && typeof v === 'object'){
            this._hiddenChild = v;
      }
      else {
        throw new TypeError('child property must be an object!')
      }
    },
    toJSON : function() {
      return this._hiddenChild.id;
    }
  });
```

But alas, `Object.defineProperty` doesn't take a `toJSON` descriptor.

Comment: are u asking if we can overwrite toJSON mentod?

Comment: since _v_ is an object, you can define a toJSON method on it in your setter, even as an own property it will work.

Comment: @dandavis that's exactly what I meant when I said `"We can define a toJSON for the child object"`. The problem is that toJSON method would be enacted every time you tried to stringify the object. I want it to *only* be enacted when that particular property (in this case `child`) is stringified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot define stringification behavior for single properties. You will need to put a `toJSON` method on the `parent` object itself:

```
var parent = {};
Object.defineProperty(parent, "child", {…});
parent.child = …;
parent.toJSON = function() {
    return {_actualChild:this.child, child:this.child.id};
};
```

```
> JSON.stringify(parent)
{"_actualChild":{"id":3,"name":"Jill"},"child":3}
```